# Python TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Tags: python, tkinter

It tells me "TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'" and I am really new so I can't figure out what I did wrong. When using pyCharm and hovering over the argument in set() it says "Expected type 'Variable', got 'int' instead". I don't know what that means. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
var = StringVar
hoho = 0
master = Tk()
var.set (hoho)
photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\josa\\Downloads\\Kappa.pmm")
w = Label(image=photo)
w.photo = photo
w.pack()
w = Label(master, text=var, )
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

PS: sorry for asking a question that might seem dumb

Comment: fix your typo in `var = StringVar()`,  add this instruction before that: `root = Tk()` and modify the last line to `root.mainloop()` ... and do **not hurry** to ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following line is missing `()`

```
var = StringVar()
               ^^
```

And creation of `StringVar` should be done after creating root windows:

```
master = Tk()
var = StringVar()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parentheses after `StringVar`. it should be `StringVar()`, because the `set()` method only work on `StringVar()` object.

Your code should be like this:

```
from tkinter import *


var = StringVar() #With parentheses 
var.set("Whatever String object you want")
```

Now it should work :))